# inputAccessoryView occasionally does not receive initial touch

Tags: ios, uitextview, inputaccessoryview, uitextinput, uikeyinput

Ever since iOS 8 and custom keyboards were introduced the `inputAccessoryView` in my app occasionally drops touches. Primarily when users attempt to hit a key on it after quickly typing on the system keyboard.

If the user types slowly and presses the buttons on the `inputAccessoryView` carefully it works fine.

In an attempt to debug this issue I have overridden the `touchesBegan` method on the `UIInputView` subclass I use as my `inputAccessoryView`. The `touchesBegan` method does not get called when the user types quickly and then taps the `inputAccessoryView`.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to resolve this issue? Basically since iOS 8, and also in iOS 9, the keyboard has become a lot "laggier" and quick typing prevents the `inputAccessoryView` from receiving some touches at all.

Comment: I'm currently developing an iPad app on iOS 10.2.1 and I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve this?